# Getting the attribute from a View's Model when the view is clicked (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, underscore.js

When a user clicks on a `div` with class `.photo_container` which is part of the view `PhotoListView`, there is a function `sendSelectedPhotoId` that will be triggered. This function has to get the attribute `photo_id` from the `Photo` model that belongs to this view whose `div .photo_container` element has been clicked, and send it to the serverside via `fetch()`.

**Problem:** So far I managed to get the function `sendSelectedPhotoId` to be triggered when the `div` is clicked, but I cant figure out how to get the `photo_id` attribute of the view's `Photo` model. How should I achieve this?

On a side note, I'm not sure whether the correct `photo_id` will be send.

**Code**

```
$('#button').click( function() {

    // Retrieve photos
    this.photoList = new PhotoCollection();
    var self = this;
    this.photoList.fetch({
        success: function() {
            self.photoListView = new PhotoListView({ model: self.photoList });
            $('#photo_list').html(self.photoListView.render().el);
        }
    });
});
```

**Model & Collection**

```
// Models
Photo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        photo_id: ''
    }
});

// Collections
PhotoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Photo,
    url: 'splash/process_profiling_img'
});
```

**Views**

```
// Views
PhotoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',

    events: {
        'click .photo_container':  'sendSelectedPhotoId'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('reset', this.render, this);
        this.model.bind('add', function(photo) {
            $(this.el).append(new PhotoListItemView({ model: photo }).render().el);
        }, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        _.each(this.model.models, function(photo) {
            $(this.el).append(new PhotoListItemView({ model: photo }).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    },

    sendSelectedPhotoId: function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log(self.model.get('photo_id'));
        self.model.fetch({
            data: { chosen_photo: self.model.get('photo_id')},
            processData: true,
            success: function() {
        }});
    }

});

PhotoListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'photo_box',

    template: _.template($('#tpl-PhotoListItemView').html()),


    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.bind('destroy', this.close, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template( this.model.toJSON() ));
        return this;
    },

    close: function() {
        $(this.el).unbind();
        $(this.el).remove();
    }


});
```

### SECOND ATTEMPT

I also tried placing the event handler and `sendSelectedPhotoId` in the `PhotoListItemView` where I managed to get the Model's attribute properly, but I can't figure out how to trigger the `reset` event when the `PhotoList` collection did a fetch().

**View**

```
PhotoListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'photo_box',

    events: {
        'click .photo_container':  'sendSelectedPhotoId'
    },

    template: _.template($('#tpl-PhotoListItemView').html()),


    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.bind('destroy', this.close, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template( this.model.toJSON() ));
        return this;
    },

    close: function() {
        $(this.el).unbind();
        $(this.el).remove();
    },

    sendSelectedPhotoId: function() {
        console.log('clicked!');
        var self = this;
        console.log(self.model.get('photo_id'));
        self.model.fetch({
            data: { chosen_photo: self.model.get('photo_id')},
            processData: true,
            success: function() {
                $(this.el).html('');
        }});
    }


});
```

**Problem:** With this, I cant seem to fire the `reset` event of the model after doing the `fetch()` in function `sendSelectedPhotoId`, which means I cant get it to re-render using `PhotoListView`'s `render()`.

In the screenshot below from Chrome's javascript console, I printed out the collection after `sendSelectedPhotoId` did its `fetch()`, and it seems like the fetched *added* the new data to the existing model, instead of creating 2 new models and removing all existing model!

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `this.model` in `PhotoListView` when you're actually wrapping a collection? You should be using `new PhotoListView({ collection: ... })` and `this.collection` to avoid confusion.

Comment: And yes, I agree with mu, there are some conventions that aren't being followed in your code that is making it a little confusing to follow.

Comment: Thanks, I will change that. I learn what I did from http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/, take a look at the router code. `this.wineListView = new WineListView({model:this.wineList});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have child views for each model, so I would put the click event handler in the child view.  In the handler in the child, trigger an event passing this.model, and listen for that event in your parent.

**Update based on update:**

Try changing

```
this.model.bind('reset', this.render, this); to 
this.model.bind('remove', this.render, this);  // model is a collection right?
```

and then remove the model from the collection after the view is clicked.  Also, I don't think using Model.fetch is what you really want to do.  Maybe a .save or a custom method on the model?

**Update based on author's comment showing sample base from blog**

I would not follow that blog's advice.  If you are using backbone professionally I can't recommend the [Thoughtbot ebook](https://workshops.thoughtbot.com/products/1-backbone-js-on-rails) enough.

- It's $50 for a work in progress, and it's worth every penny
- It has a *simple* sample application that lays out how to organize a backbone app.  This is why I bought the book.
- It uses Rails in the examples for the backend, but I have used Rails, Node, and C# MVC and all work no problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, do u mean like in my second attempt as in the updated original post? I cant seem to fire the `reset` event of the model after doing the `fetch()` in function `sendSelectedPhotoId`, which means I cant get it to re-render using `PhotoListView`'s `render()`.

Comment: Thanks for the book suggestion, I dont use Ruby on Rails but PHP... wish there's a similar one with PHP backend. Noticed their webpage says I need to be comfortable with ROR.